# Using powershell (or any software), how can i display the monitors id number

Tags: powershell

In windows, I can use the identify button in the display control panel to display a number on each monitor corresponding to their ID in windows display manager.

Can I, preferably using powershell, show these ID temporarily just like clicking the button.
[image: Windows display identify button]

If it's not possible to get to show the ID as windows does it, would it be possible to popup a window in a specific monitor display ?

My goal is to get a monitor to show information on itself either by correlating display id with WMI information or by showing a window with the current monitor information.

For example, let's say i have 4 monitor in a 2x2 matrix. All the monitors are the same models, only thing that would change is the serial numbers. Using WMI, i can get information on the monitors, but is there a way to know which monitor is which physically?

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetMonitorSerial () {
        $Monitor =(Get-WmiObject -NameSpace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID -EA 0 | ForEach-Object {
            $([System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetString($($_.SerialNumberID)))
        })

        $MON0 = $Monitor[0]
        $MON1 = $Monitor[1]
    $MON2 = $Monitor[2]
    $MON3 = $Monitor[3]
        Write-Host "Monitor #0: " $MON0
        Write-Host "Monitor #1: " $MON1
    Write-Host "Monitor #2: " $MON2
    Write-Host "Monitor #3: " $MON3
    }

    GetMonitorSerial
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer but the issue remains with this option. It is easy to find out what serial number, but I don't know which physical monitor has which serials. I want to programmatically target a monitor and display that information (serial #, make, model,etc) on that specific monitor.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-MonitorSerial {
    $monitors = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                Where-Object { $_.SerialNumberID -ne $null } |
                ForEach-Object {
                    $name = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.UserFriendlyName)
                    $serial = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.SerialNumberID)
                    if ($name) {
                        Write-Host "${name}: $serial"
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "Monitor: $serial"
                    }
                }
}

Get-MonitorSerial
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a great way to get the serial number of the monitors, but how can I know which monitor has what serial. I want a way to know on what monitor the window is currently on.